# getting data from handler

Tags: android, handler

I tried some simple Bluetooth tutorial/code and it works great. Handling incoming data is made in handler. I need to restore data from that handler so I can use it in main thread, for making graph or something like that. How can I do that?

This Handler is in `onCreate`.

```
bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
      public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
          if (msg.what == handlerState) {                                     
              String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;                                                                
              recDataString.append(readMessage);                                      
              int endOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("~");                    
              if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           
                  String dataInPrint = recDataString.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);

                  if (
                         //something
                  )
                  {
                      String sensor0 = recDataString.substring(1, 3);

                    sendDataMethod(sensor0);
                  }
                  recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());                    
              }

          }
      }
  };


private void sendDataMethod(String sensor0){
Log.e("TAG",sensor0);
}
```

How can I get `sensor0` out into the main thread?

Thanks!!

Comment: create a method,call and pass data as params from handler

Comment: Can you edit your question to reduce your code example to the minimum required to demonstrate the issue? Also, please add some of the things you've tried, and how they worked out.

Comment: @DavidHempy I reduced the code as you said. I tried some bundle examples,but not sure i did it right way.

Comment: @gowtham6672 can you give me an example or link?

Comment: i have edited ur code

Comment: @gowtham6672 recDataString is string builder, but I understood the point and made it work! Thanks for your time and effort!